# array_filter() function remove 0 also why?

Tags: php, arrays

I used `array_filter()` function of PHP for filter array element and remove empty array elements but now I face issue with these function.

I have Array

```
Array
(
   [0] => 
   [1] => 0
   [2] => 
)
// when I filter above array using function array_filter() than It's gave me 
Array()
Actually I want to get Array ( [1] => 0 )
```

Why It should remove `0` value at 1st position.
Any other function than can't remove element of array that contain `0 value`

Comment: [**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#) It removes all elements which are equal to false

Comment: What exactly is an "empty" array element for you? Which values do you consider as "empty"? Same as the [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function? That function considers `0` as empty, so it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @FelixKling I actually think array element contain nothing OR whitespace

Comment: @higunjan: *"array element contain nothing"* So you mean `null`? There cannot be "nothing". Every element is a specific value. Which values do you consider to be "nothing"?